# Set the first Record Value of LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `DBSet` which is `db.Company` and it contains 3 records like

**id name is_active**

```
1 company1 1
2 company2 1
3 company3 1
```

My Created class to transfer the records:

```
public class CompanyFinal
    { 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string selected { get; set; }
    }
```

My LINQ looks like this:

```
(from h in db.Company where h.is_active == 1 select new CompanyFinal { id = h.id, name = h.name, selected = "false" }).ToList();
```

No doubt this `LINQ` is working but i need to make the first record to be `selected="true"` which is the `company 1` while doing it in LINQ.

How could i do that? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just 
var results = (from h in db.Company where h.is_active == 1 select new CompanyFinal { id = h.id, name = h.name, selected = "false" }).ToList();
            results[0].selected = true;

Comment: This comment gives a great idea since the post was started before the answers below it is because of this `results[0].selected = true;` You can post this @Rawinas if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're making a list, I think that computational the fasted method, which is also the best maintainable (understood by others) would be to just assign the first element:

(Using method syntax, showing an alternative select)

```
var resultingList = db.Company
    .Where(company => company.is_active == 1)
    .Select(company => new CompanyFinal()
    {
        id = company.id,
        name = company.name,
        selected = "false",
    })
    .ToList();
if (resultingList.Any())
   resultingList[0].selected = true;
```

If you are not sure whether you want to convert it to a list, for instance because you want to concatenate other Linq functions after it, consider using this [overload of Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var result = db.Company
    .Where(company => company.is_active == 1)
    .Select( (company, index) => new CompanyFinal()
    {
        id = company.id,
        name = company.name,
        selected = (index == 0) ? "true" : "false",
    });
```

By the way, consider changing your CompanyFinal class such that selected is a bool instead of a string, that would make your code less error prone. For instance, after construction Selected is neither "true" nor "false". Users are able to give it a value like "TRUE" or String.Empty

If your class has users that really need a string property selected instead of a Boolean property consider keeping a get property for it:

```
public class CompanyFinal
{ 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected {get; set;}

    // for old user compatability:
    public string selected
    {
        get { return this.Selected ? "true" : "false"; }
    }
}
```

The following will go wrong:

```
if (companyFinals[0].selected == "True") ...
```

versus:

```
 if (companyFinals[0].Selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

What if we define a local variable

```
               var counter = 1;
               (from h in db.Company where h.is_active == 1 select new CompanyFinal { id = h.id, name = h.name, selected =  (counter++ == 1 ? "true" :"false") }).ToList();
```

Comment: Relying on side effects is not recommended in LINQ which is based on the functional programming paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

From your result:

```
var companies = (from h in db.Company 
                   where h.is_active == 1 select h).ToList();

var companyFinals = (from h in companies 
                      select new CompanyFinal { 
                         id = h.id, 
                         name = h.name, 
                         selected = "false" 
                     }).ToList();

var firstCompany = companies.FirstOrDefault();

if (firstCompany != null) {
     firstCompany.selected = true;
}

// save result back to database
```

There is no way to do it in 1 operation other than writing a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Tran